# How to change language in Rhinoceros 5 (educational)

Tags: language

I have the Rhino 5 and I have two languages installed:

[image: rhinoceros installation]

But I can't seem to be able to switch the language to English. Where can the language be changed?

Answer (score 1):

In `C:\Program Files (x86)\Rhinoceros 5.0\System\Languages` or similar folder delete all XML files exept `1033.xml`

Don't forget to backup you files if you need to reverse the process eventually.

See [How to fix Rhinoceros 3D 5.0 Wrong language BUG!](https://youtu.be/QX__z2rFzWM)